# Override default getstream component styles into NextJS Component

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, getstream-io

How can I override the [getStream.io](https://getstream.io/) components css with custom css ? I have create the component as below and I need to override the css for the various classes of it's components.

As per this [README documentation](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react#customizing-styles) I have import the css file into my `Next.JS` component and then write my custom css of their component into the `/public/style.css` file but it is not applying any how.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StreamChat } from 'stream-chat';
import { Chat, Channel, ChannelHeader, MessageInput, MessageInputSmall, VirtualizedMessageList, Window } from 'stream-chat-react';
import 'stream-chat-react/dist/css/index.css';

const chatClient = StreamChat.getInstance(process.env.GET_STREAM_KEY);
const userToken = process.env.GET_STREAM_TOKEN;

chatClient.disconnectUser()
chatClient.connectUser({id: userId}, userToken);

const channel = chatClient.channel(process.env.TYPE, process.env.ROOM);

const ChatComponent = () => (
  <Chat client={chatClient} theme='livestream dark'>
    <Channel channel={channel}>
      <Window>
        <ChannelHeader live />
        <VirtualizedMessageList />
      </Window>
    </Channel>
  </Chat>
);

export default ChatComponent;
```

I have written the below css into style.css file to override the css of the components but below css are not applying.

```css
.str-chat-channel {
  max-height: 150px;
}

.str-chat__virtual-message__wrapper {
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 15px;
}

.str-chat__virtual-message__wrapper {
  align-items: center;
}

.str-chat__virtual-message__wrapper .str-chat__avatar--rounded {
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your `stream-chat-react` global CSS import to your [custom `_app` file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) then import your own `styles.css` after it.

```js
// pages/_app.js

import "stream-chat-react/dist/css/index.css";
import "<your-path-to>/style.css"; // Replace with the path to your `style.css`

// ...
```